# populating a dynamic dropdown with two variables

Tags: php

I have two variables set up to populate a dynamic dropdown. The variables are each arrays and run through `for each`.
The first variable queries the db to find out what staff member is currently assigned and then display that name. This name is shown in the first position of the dropdown.

The second variable queries the db to see what other staff members are available to be assigned. Those results are to be shown below the currently assigned staff member.

The issue I have is trying to get this to properly display in a list inside of the dynamic dropdown. Right now, the results are showing up where the first variable is in front of each listing for the second variable
[image]

**DESIRED RESULT**
How do I get this to properly show? The names should not be net to each other. Also variable 1 is in front of each name "brett Smith" and it should not be. It should show as:
Brett Smith
Stacy Test
Matt Mocabee

The PHP

```
    $id=$xxxx_t->_id;
    $Current_Staffing = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT First_Name, Last_Name FROM Staff_Table, Staff_List  ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC LIMIT 1");
    $On_Duty = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT Staff_Id, First_Name, Last_Name FROM Staff
foreach($On_Duty as $person){         
    $f_name_option = $person->First_Name; 
    $lname_option = $person->Last_Name;
    $staff_id = $person->Staff_id;
    echo("<option value='$staff_id, $id'")
    foreach($Current_Staffing as $staff){
        $staff->First_Name;
        $staff->Last_Name;
    }   echo(">$staff->First_Name&nbsp;$staff->Last_Name<br><br>$f_name_option&nbsp;$l_name_option</option>");
}
```

**EDIT 1** - un-nest `foreach` loops:

```
    $id=$xxxx_t->_id;
    $Current_Staffing = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT First_Name, Last_Name FROM Staff_Table, Staff_List  ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC LIMIT 1");
    $On_Duty = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT Staff_Id, First_Name, Last_Name FROM Staff
foreach($On_Duty as $person){         
    $f_name_option = $person->First_Name; 
    $person->First_Name
    $lname_option = $person->Last_Name;
    $staff_id = $person->Staff_id;
    echo("<option value='$staff_id, $id'")

}

    foreach($Current_Staffing as $staff){
        $staff->First_Name;
        $staff->Last_Name;
    }
```

echo(">$staff->First_Name $staff->Last_Name
$f_name_option $l_name_option");

The above edit does not then show the available options for the staff who could be assigned. Here is a screenshot - [image]

**EDIT 2 -**
With this code I am getting the following output. It is showing who is selected, but is doubled in the list:[image]

```
$id=$xxxx_t->_id;
    
    $On_Duty = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT Staff_Id, First_Name, Last_Name FROM Staff
foreach($On_Duty as $person){         
    $f_name_option = $person->First_Name; 
    $lname_option = $person->Last_Name;
    $staff_id = $person->Staff_id;
    echo("<option value='$staff_id, $id'>$person->First_Name&nbsp;$person->Last_Name</option>");
}
$Current_Staffing = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT First_Name, Last_Name FROM Staff_Table, Staff_List  ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC LIMIT 1");
    foreach($Current_Staffing as $staff){
        $staff_id = $staff->Staff_id;
        echo("<option value='$staff_id, $id'>$staff->First_Name&nbsp;$staff->Last_Name</option>");
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `>$staff->First_Name&nbsp;$staff->Last_Name<br><br>` from your last echo statement?

Comment: Wouldnt that prevent me from seeing the output of `$Current_Staffing`

Comment: But it seems that your `<option>` tags have two names printing and removing the first ones would remove the same name from printing, because it's outside your forEach loop

Comment: Understood. just tried it and I then loose who is currently assigned. I do get the list of the others. So maybe the question is how to better show the currently assigned staff member along with all the other possible staff members?

Comment: You would need to clarify what you're looking for

Comment: I need the names not to show next to each other -

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227651/discussion-between-da-mahdi03-and-user14955679).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to put your `option` tags together inside your `forEach` loops just for easier HTML insertion and readability. You also want to "un-nest" your `for` loops because you aren't dealing with nested data, the data you have is mutually exclusive from each other. Since you want `$Current_Staffing` to come first, I suggest bringing that loop first.

Since you want to make sure that the person currently working is not listed twice (since they would belong to all employees) we can employ an `if` statement to make sure to skip them

I took the liberty of cleaning up some of the code for you as well:

```
//Global Variables
$currentEmployee = ""; //Assuming you only have one current employee, you will need to change your code if you have more than one
$id=$xxxx_t->_id;
    
$Current_Staffing = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT First_Name, Last_Name FROM Staff_Table, Staff_List  ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC LIMIT 1");
    foreach($Current_Staffing as $staff){
        $firstName = $staff->First_Name;
        $lastName = $staff->Last_Name;
        $staff_id = $staff->Staff_id;
        $currentEmployee = $firstName . " " . $lastName;
        echo("<option value='$staff_id, $id'>$firstName&nbsp;$lastName</option>");
    }   

    $On_Duty = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT Staff_Id, First_Name, Last_Name FROM Staff
foreach($On_Duty as $person){         
    $f_name_option = $person->Staff_First_Name;
    $firstName = $person->First_Name;
    $lastName = $person->Last_Name;
    $staff_id = $person->Staff_id;
    //If the person we are looking at is not the current employee then we can add them, else skip
    if ($firstName . " " . $lastName != $currentEmployee) {
        echo("<option value='$staff_id, $id'>$firstName&nbsp;$lastName</option>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks much. Just tried this but same result without a space between them is all

Comment: What are you looking for?

Comment: The names are not showing correctly. They should not be next to each other.